# Binding a radio button value to an attribute of a nested object in form backing object

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using Spring boot with thymeleaf.

FORM BACKING BEAN:

```
public class TermReportForm {
    private long gradeid;
    private String gradenumber;
    private Grading grading;}
```

NESTED OBJECT GRADING IN FORM BACKING BEAN WHICH HAS TO BE POPULATED BY USER INPUT:

```
public class Grading {    
    private String activity;
    private int performance;}
```

MY FORM:

```
<form class="form-group" th:action="@{/createtermreportforstudent}" th:object="${trf}" method="post"> 
      <div class="form-group" id="TextBoxDiv0">
     <th:block th:id="grading" >
               <input th:id="activity" th:name="activity"  th:field="*{grading.activity}"/>
               <label class="radio-inline">
               <input th:name="performance" th:value="1" type="radio" th:field="*{grading.performance}"/>1</label>
               <label class="radio-inline">
               <input th:name="performance" th:value="2" type="radio" th:field="*{grading.performance}"/> 2 </label>
               <label class="radio-inline">
                  <input th:name="performance" th:value="3" type="radio" th:field="*{grading.performance}"/> 3 </label> 


      </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button> 
     </form>
```

The problem is that the attribute "performance" (radio button) in the nested object "grading" is not getting populated with the user choice. On the other hand, the attribute "activity" (text input) of the nested object is getting populated just fine. Where I am going wrong?

Comment: I tried the same code and is working fine, please verify the value of grading is correct before render in the html

Comment: I am creating a new instance of TermReportForm and putting it in model to serve as the form backing bean for the form. Not created a new instance of Grading explicity since I assume it will be created when TermReportForm is instantiated. When the form is filled by user, it is showing '0' value for performance atribute in the receiving controller method. The activity attribute is populated correctly.

Comment: Turns out my setter method for performance attribute was missing! Thanks for the help.

Comment: nice you found the problem